# how to make pip works again?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I tried to make pip3 as the main pip in my Linux by writing this code

```
alias pip=pip3
```

and after that what ever command I give to pip, it keeps on giving the same error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Comment: are you using python3?

Comment: This can happen on Debian due to how pip is packaged (wrapper script doesn't work with pip redesign). How did you install pip3? Did you update it after you installed it? If so how?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ yes on linux debian

Comment: So the problem is that it is looking for 'pip' . So install pip! though I must also say, there must be wrong with the way you installed pip3

Comment: @wjandrea well, as I remember I installed it from the  terminal, I tried to update it and it was updated but still it gives the same message.

Comment: you think I should uninstall it and then reinstall it again?

Comment: If you try this  `python3 -m pip install --user packagename`it still throws the error ?

Comment: @Razan There's more than one way to install it from the terminal. Do you remember how exactly you did it? and how you updated it?

Comment: @wjandrea sudo apt install python3-pip

Comment: @dejdej it worked! thank you!

Comment: and thank you all for you concern and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `python3 -m pip install --user packagename`

Answer (score 2):

For linux, you can use the argument `-m` of python bin.

```
python3 -m pip
```

so, you can use this allias

```
alias pip="python3 -m pip"
```

Comment: and the messages were

Comment: I don't know how to write codes in the comments here

Comment: @RazanSrour add additional information like this to your question, i.e add a section with `I have also tried to .... and the result was ....`. Otherwise it will e hard to follow what you have tried already

Comment: Which command did you type ? Any other error message with usage displayed ?.
If you juste typed `python -m pip`, yes, this will print usage, because it's default behaviour if you call pip without argument.

Comment: @FlyingTeller you're right I'll take that into account

Comment: @iElden well before giving this command <alias pip="python3 -m pip"> ,,, pip never gave me the usage nor the commands